# Characteristic function, convergence in distribution

Tags: characteristic-functions

Problem: Let $X_{1},\ X_{2},\ \cdots$ be independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables having the ch.f. of the term $1-c|t|^{a}+o(|t|^{a})$ as $t\to0$, where $0<a\leq2$. Determine the constants $b$ and $c$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}/(bn^{c})$ converges in distribution to a random variable having ch.f. $e^{-|t|^{a}}.$

I have completed this problem, but condition $0<a\leq2$ is not used. I don't konw what's wrong in my answer. Anyone can help me? Thank in advance. Here are my answer.

Since $X_{1},\ X_{2},\ \cdots$ are i.i.d., so the ch.f. of  $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}/(bn^{c})$ is
\begin{align*}
 \varphi(t)\stackrel{def}{=} \varphi_{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}/(bn^{c})}(t) & =Ee^{it\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}/(bn^{c})} 
    =\prod_{i=1}^{n}Ee^{it X_{i}/(bn^{c})} \\
   & =\prod_{i=1}^{n}\varphi_{X_{i}}(t/(bn^{c}))\\
   &=\left[\varphi_{X_{i}}(\frac{t}{bn^{c}})\right]^{n}\\
   &=\left[1-c\left|\frac{t}{bn^{c}}\right|^{a}+o(\left|\frac{t}{bn^{c}}\right|^{a}) \right]^{n}
\end{align*}
By L$\acute{e}$vy continuity theorem, we know that $
\varphi(t)\longrightarrow e^{-|t|^{a}}$ ,then
$$
nlog\left[1-c\left|\frac{t}{bn^{c}}\right|^{a}+o(\left|\frac{t}{bn^{c}}\right|^{a})\right]\longrightarrow -|t|^{a}.
$$
By Taylor expansion, $log(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-x)^{n}/n$, so
$$
\begin{cases}
  ac=1 &  \\
   \frac{c}{|b|^{a}}=1 &
\end{cases}
\Longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
  c=\frac{1}{a} &  \\
   b=\pm\frac{1}{a}^{\frac{1}{a}} & .
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: You are assuming that there is convergence for some $b$ and $c$ and just showing how to find these constants. The provblem it to show that there is convergence when you choose these values of $b$ and $c$.